# Read content of *multipart.FileHeader into []byte

Tags: file, go, byte

How can I read the body/content of a file contained in a *multipart.FileHeader into a slice of bytes ([]byte) in GO.

The only thing I got to work was reading the content into a slice of bytes with a huge size, but of course I want the exact size of the file.
I want to hash the file content with md5 afterwards.

```
// file is a *multipart.FileHeader gotten from http request.
fileContent, _ := file.Open()
var byteContainer []byte
byteContainer = make([]byte, 1000000)
fileContent.Read(byteContainer)
fmt.Println(byteContainer)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [ioutil.ReadAll](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll)

https://play.golang.org/p/FUgPAZ9w2X.

In your case do;

```
byteContainer, err := ioutil.ReadAll(fileContent) // you may want to handle the error
fmt.Printf("size:%d", len(byteContainer))
```

You may also want to see this example from `multipart` [package docs](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#Reader),
https://play.golang.org/p/084tWn65-d

Comment: Works perfectly ! Thank you ! Long names, I agree. :) I spent way too much time figuring how to read that file correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
func createContextWithFile(filePath string) *gin.Context {
    // Открываем файл
    fmt.Println(filePath)
    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error opening file:", err)
        return nil
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // Создаем пустой HTTP-запрос и ответ
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "/upload", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating request:", err)
        return nil
    }

    // Создаем объект MultipartWriter и устанавливаем граничное значение
    body := &bytes.Buffer{}
    writer := multipart.NewWriter(body)
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())

    // Создаем форму для файла
    filePart, err := writer.CreateFormFile("file", "file.txt")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error creating form file:", err)
        return nil
    }

    // Копируем содержимое файла в форму
    _, err = io.Copy(filePart, file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error copying file content:", err)
        return nil
    }

    // Завершаем запись в тело запроса
    err = writer.Close()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error closing writer:", err)
        return nil
    }

    // Устанавливаем тело запроса и его длину
    req.Body = io.NopCloser(body)
    req.ContentLength = int64(body.Len())

    w := httptest.NewRecorder()

    // Создаем контекст Gin с прикрепленным файлом
    ginContext, _ := gin.CreateTestContext(w)
    ginContext.Request = req

    return ginContext
}

func main() {

    ginContext := createContextWithFile("test_files/file_success.xlsx")

    if ginContext == nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to create Gin context")
        return
    }

    // Получаем файл из контекста
    file, err := ginContext.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("FormFile error: %s\n", err.Error())
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).